# Generic type interface that accepts both types of Collection<T> and <T>

Tags: java, generics, java-8

The following `Interface` allows me to do `displayReuestResponse<String>` etc:

```
public interface RequestResponse<T> 
{
    void displayRequestResponse(T output);
}
```

On the other hand the following `Interface` allows me to do pass in either `LinkedHashSet` or `ArrayList`:

```
public interface RequestResponse<T>
{
    void displayRequestResponse(Collection<T> output);
}
```

I am just curious, could we even make it more generic by having (tweaking) an `Interface` that can accept both types? Or is this not possible?

Comment: The second interface doesn't allow you to pass in an ArrayList

Comment: The first can accept both types (and more)...

Comment: @assylias yes but not at the same time

Comment: Just for the sake of the argument, in your theoretical implementation, how would a method that accepted both things look like?

Comment: I still don’t get the question. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with java 8 you can do something like

```
interface RequestResponse<T>     {

    default void displayRequestResponse(Collection<? extends T> output) {
        output.foreach(this::displayRequestResponse);
    }

    void displayRequestResponse(T output);
}
```

So you wouldn't have to implement the overload that takes a collection in every concrete implementation.

Comment: You simply assume that that collection version is just a repeated variant of the single element version, which is rather unlikely. What if I don't want that?

Comment: @Unheilig: this *is* type-safe.

Comment: @zeroflag the OP was asking for a way to handle an item and a collection of items in the same method. I therefore made an assumption that they would want something like this.

Comment: @Unheilig this is type safe - the generic type T is bound when you instantiate. So if you create a RequestResponse<String> you can pass either a single String, or any collection of Strings.

Comment: Edited so that the collection overload uses a bounded wildcard. Now for RequestResponse<Number> you can pass a List<Number> or a List<Double> in; previously only List<Number> would have worked

Answer (score 2):

What about just overloading?

```
interface RequestResponse<T>
{
    void displayRequestResponse(Collection<T> output);
    void displayRequestResponse(T output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have interface, that has two methods:

```
public interface RequestResponse<T>
{
    void displayRequestResponse(Collection<T> output);

    void displayRequestResponse(T output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that this will work in a type safe way.

A `Collection<T>` and `T` are two completely different types that have nothing in common. What would an implementation of an interface like that do exactly?

It can't loop through the `Collection<T>` if you just passed a `T` and it can't do any operations on a `Collection<T>` that are only defined for `T`.

You can however use overloading and defaults to achieve your desired result of having one implementation covering both cases:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {

    default void doSomething(T oneT) {
        doSomething(Arrays.asList(oneT));
    }

    void doSomething(Collection<T> multipleTs);
}
```

This way you will only have to provide the implementation for the `Collection<T>` case, but you will also be able to invoke the single element version.

Of course you can also do this the other way around and use forEach as in [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28835450/3699808)

Comment: Potential downside of this vs my answer is the overhead of wrapping single arguments in an array. On the other hand, if there is processing to be done that requires that the arguments are a Collection than this is the way to go. Depends on the situation.

Comment: So you say that having the abstract `displayRequestResponse(T output);` I can't pass a `List<String>` to the concrete `displayRequestResponse(List<String> output)`?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(oneT)` is unnecessary overhead due to the array creation. Just use [`Collections.singleton(oneT)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-).

Comment: @Holger you're still newing up a wrapper object there - there is still an overhead

Comment: @Tom McIntyre: if you want to represent an object as a `Collection`, wrapping it is unavoidable. But it’s not necessary to create an array of size one, store the object to the array and wrap the array when there is a standard solution for just wrapping the instance.

Comment: Thanks for input. +1. So, in this case, there is no way to ensure type safety? Could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
public interface RequestResponse<T> {
    void displayRequestResponse(T output);
}

public class StringReqResp implements RequestResponse<String> {
    @Override
    public void displayRequestResponse(String output) {
        // Do what you need with the String 
    }
}

public class StringListReqResp implements RequestResponse<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public void displayRequestResponse(List<String> output) {
        // Do what you need with the list of String
    }
}
```